# open multiple ssh session in a predefined layout

Tags: ssh, putty

Is there a way on Windows 10 to open multiple SSH connections in a predefined window layout? I have been using MTPutty for this, and it works well, except that I have to configure the layout every time manually.

Ideally I could be able to login and run a command automatically in each connection, but my main problem is having to manually define the layout each time.

I have found many threads on this and other sites that are concerned with preserving SSH sessions. This is not what I want, I think. I'm fine with logging in to each window, I just need them automatically arranged in predefined positions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a question of taste. Personally I use the (awesome) windows terminal application.

When you open up Windows Terminal, by default it will open up a single tab with a single pane, using your default profile. However, if you wish to customize this start-up layout, you can use the `wt` command with command line arguments.

Installing Windows Terminal adds `wt` to the system path, so you can invoke it without having to specify the path. On it's own, `wt` will start up just a new instance of Windows Terminal, but it also has sub-commands for split-pane and new-tab, which allow you to set up the layout how you like.

The split-pane and new-tab commands both take a `-p` parameter which allows you to specify the the type of profile you want to open, referenced either by name or guid (you can find these in the settings.json file), and a -d parameter if you want to override the starting directory. Additionally, for split-pane you can specify -H or -V to split the pane horizontally or vertically.

You can use a `;` in the command to string multiple sub-commands together. For example:

```
wt ; new-tab -p "SSH" ; split-pane -p "Ubuntu" -V; split-pane -p "SSH" -H -d "/home/myuser"
```

Comment: I ended up launching `wt` from an AutioIt script and sending it some keystrokes to split panes as needed. Not perfect solution, I was hoping to something more robust and configurable, but it works fine for my purposes. Thanks.